# Perforce - how to secure branch mappings

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to lock down branch mappings so that all user can view/use them, but only administrators can edit? My users use the same few branch mappings all the time, and I would like to make sure no one accidentally changes one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this from the command line ([this link may be useful for that](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_branch.html)) but in P4V you can open your branch mapping for edit and check the "locked" checkbox. This will mean only the owner (original creator) can modify the mapping. About the locked property:

> Either unlocked (the default) or locked.
>
> If locked, only the Owner: can modify the branch mapping, and the mapping can't be deleted until it is unlocked.

[image: Checking the locked box on the branch mapping means only the owner can change it.]

Answer (score 1):

Using the locked field is a simple way to accomplish what you need, as already shown and stated.

If you were trying to do anything else such as prevent or allow 'specific users' to edit branch mappings then you would have to use the Perforce Broker which can intercept and deny the 'p4 branch' command to whomever you choose. (The Perforce Broker is a server process that mediates between Perforce client applications and Perforce servers, including proxy servers.)

REFERENCES

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4dist/chapter.broker.html

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Installing-P4Broker-on-Windows-and-Unix-systems

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Writing-Filter-Programs-for-P4Broker

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/P4Broker-and-Protections

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-Double-Quotes-in-Broker-Filter-Scripts